# How to proof that a line is an approximation of an data set?

Tags: proof-writing, graphing-functions

In graph x there is an input of an data set 1, which computes to a line a, which is approximated with line b.

How can I proof that line b is an approximation of line a and goes on infinite?

**EDIT** here the my try to proof it

Given the function 
$$
    \delta (x) = \frac{\gamma(x+1)}{\gamma(x)}
$$

To show that 
$$
\lim x\rightarrow\infty \sum_{x=1}^{\infty} \delta (x) = \infty 
$$
Let k be the limit of $$\delta (x)
$$
$$
\lim x\rightarrow k \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\gamma(x+1)}{\gamma(x)}=k
$$
Be $$x=k$$
$$c +\frac{\gamma(k+1)}{\gamma(k)}=k \rightarrow \gamma(k)= \frac{\gamma(k+1)}{k}+\frac{c\gamma(k+1)}{k}=\frac{2c\gamma(k+1)}{k}
$$
Be $$x = k + 1$$
$$\gamma(k+1)=\frac{2c\gamma(k+1)\gamma(k+2)}{k}=k \rightarrow k= \frac{2c\gamma(k+1)\gamma(k+2)}{\gamma (k+1)}
$$
$$
c +\frac{\gamma(k+1)}{\gamma(k)} \neq 2c\gamma(k+2)
$$

qed

Is this proof correct?

Comment: I proof $\to$ I prove.

Comment: Any line is an "approximation" of any other line. But some approximations are better than others. You will need to tell us how you are approximating this line, and what criteria you are trying to satisfy before anyone can help you find what you are after.